# "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value" when using CombineScriptsHandler.axd

Tags: asp.net, exception, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've enabled CombineScriptsHandler.axd as mentioned in the link below.

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ToolkitScriptManager/ToolkitScriptManager.aspx

The handler is working as expected but sometimes it throws the following exception...

Message: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value"
Source: mscorlib
TargetSite: Boolean Parse(System.String) Stack Trace: at System.Boolean.Parse(String value) at AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManagerCombiner.OutputCombinedScriptFile(HttpContextBase context) at AjaxControlToolkit.CombineScriptsHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Any suggestions?

Thanks